# Filtering out the nearest date from an array

Tags: java, jquery, date

I have a scenario where i want to select the nearest date or the past date from a bunch of data which i am getting from a ajax call.

For example: If I am getting three rows with three different date like 12/12/2018, 12/3/2018 and 1/1/2018 then I want to return 1/1/2018.
And also if the array doesn't contains past date then it should return the nearest date to the current date.

Please suggest me something to achieve this.

Comment: Please, update your question with some data that you have from the AJAX call.

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward: Calculate the difference between now and the date and return the smallest. You should try implementing it and ask a question if you encounter a specific problem. Also: You sure the Java tag is correct? The jquery tag makes me think that you might rather need a JavaScript solution.

Comment: The combination of tags java and jquery is pretty weird, did you mean javascript instead?

Comment: Nearest past date if there is one, or just nearest date in either the past or future? If the bunch includes Dec 16, 2017 and Jan 10, 2018 and today is Jan 4, 2018, which of the two do you want?

Comment: How are your dates represented? `java.time.LocalDate` objects? In Java this would be the standard and recommended representation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a function like this would be useful:

```
function getNearestDate(dates, date) {

    if (!dates || dates.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!date) {
        date = new Date();
    }
    var result = dates[0];
    var dt = Math.abs(new Date(dates[0])-date);
    var minimum = dt;

    for (var i=1;i<dates.length;i++) {
        dt = Math.abs(new Date(dates[i])-date);
        if (dt < minimum) {
            result = dates[i];
            minimum = dt;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```